# How can I prevent the Angular async pipe from making frequent server calls when no results come back?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using the `async` pipe in an ngFor to watch an Observable.  The Observable is created by a service that hits my server, and on load time when ngFor loop is enumerated, the service correctly makes a call to the server.

Now for the part I don't understand:  when any results come back everything happens as expected.  But if the server responds with say, a 404 and no results are available for enumeration, the `async` pipe causes the service to continue to fire requests, milliseconds apart.  This is obviously no good.  What's the design expectation here and how can I gracefully handle an Observable that returns an error while using an async pipe?

In the Component template:

```
<li *ngFor="let person of persons | async">{{person.id}}</li>
```

In the Component body:

```
get persons: Observable<Person[]> {
    return this.personService.list();
}
```

In the Service:

```
list(): Observable<Person[]> {
    if (this.persons && this.persons.length) {
        return Observable.from([this.persons]);
    } else {
        return this.http.get('/person')
            .map((response: Response) => response.json())
            .map((data: Person[]) => {
                this.persons = data;
                return data;
            })
            .catch((error: any) => {
                let errMsg = "some error..."
                return Observable.throw(errMsg);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it happens because this.persons is not initialized and angular change detection works here. try under your catch handler to something like this - this.persons = []   and see if it stops fire additional requests.
Tell me if it solve the issue

Comment: Well that catch is in the Service, so maybe I should be returning a Observable of empty Person[] instead of throwing the error.  I'll try that when I have a chance and report back.  Good idea! (though then I lose the error message)

Comment: Agree.if it exist in the service then return observable with empty array. Does it help?

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue? I ran into it, too

Comment: @Dethariel I have not yet, but i'm going to have to in the coming weeks.  I'll report back once I look into it.  I haven't actually tried galvan's solution since posing this question.  At the same time, if you figure it out post an answer here please!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had a very similar issue, and it was due to how Angular2 change detection works. There are multiple solutions that worked for me.

#### Save a reference to observable so that it doesn't change

Right now your when you call `persons` getter, it always returns a **new** instance of `Observable` (e.g. a different object), so Angular reevaluates the whole thing, and during the next change detection cycle, it does it once again, and then again, ... So, this is how it can be solved:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-comp',
    template: `{{ _persons | async }}`,
}) export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        this._persons = this.personService.list();
    }
}
```

#### Change the `ChangeDetectionStrategy` to `OnPush`

You may want to tell Angular: "I know what I'm doing, I'll tell you myself when some change occurred":

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    selector: 'my-comp',
    template: `
      {{ persons | async }}
      <button (click)="reload">Reload</button>
    `,
}) export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.persons = this.personService.list();
    }

    reload() {
        this.persons = this.personService.list();
        // this tells Angular that a change occurred
        this.cd.markForCheck();
    }
}
```

Both of these solutions worked for me, and I decided to go with the second approach, since it's also an optimization

Comment: I had the same problem, oddly enough I had to do subscribe: ´this.personService.list().subscribe()´ and then ´{{ persons | async }}´. The problem seems to be with how the async-pipe deals with change detection.

Answer (score 1):

Angular will check for changes when an even occurs.
It means it will call the variables present in the template to see if their result changed or not.

If at each call you return a different object or array (even if the content is the same) angular will consider the content to have changed and refresh the template (resubscribing from the async pipe).

In your case you are calling "persons" which will return every time a different observable.

One solution is to affect the observable to a local variable and then to use this local variable in the template. Something like that:

```
class myComponent {
    public $persons: Observable<Person[]>;
    constructor() {
        this.$persons = this.$getPersons();
    }
    
    private $getPersons(): Observable<Person[]> {
        return this.personService.list();
    }
}
```

And your template

```
<li *ngFor="let person of $persons | async">{{person.id}}</li>
```

Another way is to use the decorator @Memoize which will cache the result of the method and return the same object once for all.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-memoize

Keep your code and just add the decorator it to your getter:

```
@Memoize()
get persons: Observable<Person[]> {
    return this.personService.list();
}
```

Bonus:
You probably want to cache the last value received from your service (reason why you have the "if condition"). You should consider using a replay ([publishLast or publishReplay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44412070/rxjs-publishreplay-vs-publishlast))