# RxJS publishReplay vs publishLast

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am implementing caching HTTP results in Angular application. From what I know both of the following code works, but I need to know if they are doing **exactly** the same thing, or I am missing something important?

**publishLast**

```
getPosts() {
    if( !this.posts$ ) {
      this.posts$ = this.http.get('api').publishLast().refCount();
      return this.posts$;
    }

    return this.posts$;
  }
```

**publishReplay**

```
getPosts() {
  if( !this.posts$ ) {
    this.posts$ = this.http.get('api').publishReplay(1).refCount();
       return this.posts$;
  }

  return this.posts$;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`publishLast` shares (as the name suggests) the **last** emitted value - which can only be determined when the stream **completes**.

`publishReplay(1)` shares the **latest** emitted value, which is done after any emission.

---

In the case of `this.http.get(...)` the behavior is the same, because the stream will complete after the result was received, thus the **last** and the **latest** value are the same thing.

You will have a different result though for streams that emit more than one value or that do not complete immediately after the emission of this value.

Comment: But what about errors? When the HTTP service emits an error, it doesn't call complete.

Comment: Correct, but in that case you would not have an emission in either case - you would only get an error - I would also advise you against directly publishing an http-request - you should rather subscribe it and then publish the data into a perpetual `ReplaySubject` (or `BehaviorSubject`) if the request was successful or handle the error at that central place if it was not successful.

Comment: Publishlatest actually replays the last good value AND error (if there are both). This is because it uses replaysubject